# FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore: Images are not being displayed in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm having troubles when trying to load images with Glide or Picasso in a RecyclerView with FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. I make a query and I get the data I want but when loading my RecyclerView every data is loaded correctly except images.
FirebaseFirestoreUI library I am using:
`implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.0'`

I've been looking for several days now, and I have no idea what to do.
Thanks in advance.

My database:
[FIRESTORE DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg4KZ.jpg)

Here is my code:

AdCamisetas.java(Adapter)

```
public class AdCamisetas extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Camiseta,AdCamisetas.CamisetaHolder> {

    CamisetaHolder holder;

    public AdCamisetas(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Camiseta> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CamisetaHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Camiseta camiseta) {

        this.holder = holder;
        //Glide.with(holder.itemImg.getContext()).asBitmap().load(R.drawable.noimage).into(holder.itemImg);
        System.out.println("IMAGEN" + camiseta.getImagen());
        Picasso.get().load(camiseta.toString()).into(holder.itemImg);
        holder.itemNomimg.setText(camiseta.getImagen());
        holder.itemColimg.setText(camiseta.getColor());
        holder.itemTallaimg.setText(camiseta.getTalla());
        holder.itemEstiloimg.setText(camiseta.getEstilo());

        holder.itemImg.setOnClickListener(view -> Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "IMAGEN---" + camiseta.getImagen(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()); //HERE I GET THE URL       //FROM FIRESTORE
        //holder.img.setOnLongClickListener(view -> false);
        //holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CamisetaHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.itemps, parent, false);
        return new CamisetaHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        if(getItemCount() == 0)
        {
        }
    }

    public class CamisetaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView itemImg;
        TextView itemNomimg;
        TextView itemColimg;
        TextView itemTallaimg;
        TextView itemEstiloimg;

        public CamisetaHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImg);
            itemNomimg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemNomimg);
            itemColimg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemColimg);
            itemTallaimg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTallaimg);
            itemEstiloimg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemEstiloimg);
        }
    }
}
```

Camiseta.java(POJO/OBJECT CLASS)

```
public class Camiseta{
    private String imagen;
    private String nombre;
    private String color;
    private String estilo;
    private String talla;


    public Camiseta() {

    }

    public Camiseta(String imagen, String nombre, String color, String estilo,String talla) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.color = color;
        this.estilo = estilo;
        this.talla = talla;
    }

    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getEstilo() {
        return estilo;
    }

    public String getTalla() {
        return talla;
    }

}
```

HomeFragment.java(FRAGMENT WHERE IS LOADED THE DATA with several recycler views)

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    View v;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DocumentReference userRef;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;

    private static final int COD_SOLICITADO = 1;
    private TextView txtGeneral;
    private Button btnCompartir;
    LoadingDialog cargando;

    RecyclerView recyclerPantalones, recyclerCalzado;
    AdCamisetas adCamisetas;
    AdPantalones adPantalones;
    AdCalzado adCalzado;

    //ArrayList<Camiseta> listaCamisetas;
    //ArrayList<Pantalon> listaPantalones;
    //ArrayList<Calzado> listaCalzado;

    private String nombreUsuario;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        cargando = new LoadingDialog(getActivity());
        cargando.startLoadingDialog();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#6774BC"));

        btnCompartir = v.findViewById(R.id.btnCompartir);
        txtGeneral = v.findViewById(R.id.txtGeneral);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        userRef = db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        rellenaRecyclerCamisetas();
        rellenaRecyclerPantalones();
        rellenaRecyclerCalzado();

        setNombreUsuario();

        verificarPermisos();

        btnCompartir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Esto NO Funciona", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adCamisetas.startListening();
        adPantalones.startListening();
        adCalzado.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adCamisetas.stopListening();
        adPantalones.stopListening();
        adCalzado.stopListening();

    }

    private void rellenaRecyclerCamisetas() {

        Query q = db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .collection("camisetas").orderBy("nombre");

        q.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d("AQUI------------", "DOC " + document.getData());
//HERE I SEE DATA IS RETREIVED CORRECTLY FROM DATABASE

                    }
                }
            }
        });



        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Camiseta> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Camiseta>()
                .setQuery(q, Camiseta.class)
                .build();

        adCamisetas = new AdCamisetas(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerCamisetas = v.findViewById(R.id.rCamisetas);
        recyclerCamisetas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recyclerCamisetas.setAdapter(adCamisetas);
        cargando.dismissDialog();




        /*
        Query q1 = userRef.collection("camisetas");

        List<String> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
        userRef.collection("camisetas")
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    documentList.add(document.getId());
                    cargando.dismissDialog();
                }

                for (String doc : documentList) {
                    userRef.collection("camisetas")
                            .document(doc)
                            .get().addOnCompleteListener(task2 -> {
                        if (task2.isSuccessful() && task2.getResult() != null) {

                            String id = task2.getResult().getString("id");
                            String img = task2.getResult().getString("img");
                            String nombre = task2.getResult().getString("nombre");
                            String color = task2.getResult().getString("color");
                            String talla = task2.getResult().getString("talla");
                            String estilo = task2.getResult().getString("estilo");

                            //listaImgsPs.add(img);
                            //listaNomImgsPs.add(nombre);
                            Camiseta camiseta = new Camiseta(img, nombre, color, talla, estilo);
                            System.out.println("CAMISETA --> " + camiseta.toString());
                            //listaCamisetas.add(camiseta);
                            //ParteSuperior obPs = new ParteSuperior(color,talla,estilo);


                            cargando.dismissDialog();
                        } else {
                            //alertarErrorCarga();
                            cargando.dismissDialog();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                //alertar
                cargando.dismissDialog();
            }
            cargando.dismissDialog();
        });

        adapterCamisetas = new AdapterCamisetas(getActivity(), listaCamisetas);
        recyclerCamisetas.setAdapter(adapterCamisetas);
        */
    }

    private void rellenaRecyclerPantalones() {


        Query q = db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .collection("pantalones").orderBy("nombre");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Pantalon> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Pantalon>()
                .setQuery(q, Pantalon.class)
                .build();

        adPantalones = new AdPantalones(options);

        RecyclerView rPantalones = v.findViewById(R.id.rPantalones);
        rPantalones.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        rPantalones.setAdapter(adPantalones);
        cargando.dismissDialog();

        /*
        List<String> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
        userRef.collection("pantalones")
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    documentList.add(document.getId());
                    cargando.dismissDialog();
                }

                for (String doc : documentList) {
                    userRef.collection("pantalones")
                            .document(doc)
                            .get().addOnCompleteListener(task2 -> {
                        if (task2.isSuccessful() && task2.getResult() != null) {

                            String id = task2.getResult().getString("id");
                            String img = task2.getResult().getString("img");
                            String nombre = task2.getResult().getString("nombre");
                            String color = task2.getResult().getString("color");
                            String talla = task2.getResult().getString("talla");
                            String estilo = task2.getResult().getString("estilo");

                            //listaImgsPs.add(img);
                            //listaNomImgsPs.add(nombre);
                            Pantalon pantalon = new Pantalon(img, nombre, color, talla, estilo);
                            listaPantalones.add(pantalon);
                            //ParteSuperior obPs = new ParteSuperior(color,talla,estilo);

                            adapterPantalones = new AdapterPantalones(getActivity(), listaPantalones);
                            recyclerPantalones.setAdapter(adapterPantalones);
                            cargando.dismissDialog();
                        } else {
                            //alertarErrorCarga();
                            cargando.dismissDialog();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                //alertar
                cargando.dismissDialog();
            }
        });

        */
    }

    private void rellenaRecyclerCalzado() {

        Query q = db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .collection("calzado").orderBy("nombre");

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Calzado> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Calzado>()
                .setQuery(q, Calzado.class)
                .build();

        adCalzado = new AdCalzado(options);

        RecyclerView rCalzado = v.findViewById(R.id.rCalzado);
        rCalzado.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        rCalzado.setAdapter(adCalzado);
        cargando.dismissDialog();

/*
        List<String> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
        userRef.collection("calzado")
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    documentList.add(document.getId());
                    cargando.dismissDialog();
                }

                for (String doc : documentList) {
                    userRef.collection("calzado")
                            .document(doc)
                            .get().addOnCompleteListener(task2 -> {
                        if (task2.isSuccessful() && task2.getResult() != null) {

                            String id = task2.getResult().getString("id");
                            String img = task2.getResult().getString("img");
                            String nombre = task2.getResult().getString("nombre");
                            String color = task2.getResult().getString("color");
                            String talla = task2.getResult().getString("talla");
                            String estilo = task2.getResult().getString("estilo");

                            //listaImgsPs.add(img);
                            //listaNomImgsPs.add(nombre);
                            Calzado calzado = new Calzado(img, nombre, color, talla, estilo);
                            listaCalzado.add(calzado);
                            //ParteSuperior obPs = new ParteSuperior(color,talla,estilo);

                            adapterCalzado = new AdapterCalzado(getActivity(), listaCalzado);
                            recyclerCalzado.setAdapter(adapterCalzado);
                            cargando.dismissDialog();
                        } else {
                            //alertarErrorCarga();
                            cargando.dismissDialog();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                //alertar
                cargando.dismissDialog();
            }
        });

        */
    }

    private void setNombreUsuario() {
        userRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                String name = task.getResult().getString("name");
                txtGeneral.setText("BIENVENIDO A TU ARMARIO, " + name);
            } else {
                txtGeneral.setText("BIENVENIDO A TU ARMARIO, USUARIO");
            }
        });
    }

    private void verificarPermisos() {
        String[] permisos = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                permisos[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                permisos[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                permisos[2]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"PERMISOS VERIFICADOS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permisos, COD_SOLICITADO);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        verificarPermisos();
    }


}
```

The result I get:
[EMULATOR VIEW WITH EMPTY IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkvZE.png)

ítems.xml(Layout for RecyclerView items)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="14dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemNomimg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/negro"
        android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
        tools:text="Nombre del item" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemColimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/negro"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
            android:text="Color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTallaimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/negro"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
            android:text="Talla" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemEstiloimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/negro"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/antic"
            android:text="Estilo" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does `System.out.println("IMAGEN" + camiseta.getImagen());` print?

Comment: The image Url from Firestore

Comment: If you add that URL into a browser is it working?

Comment: Yeah, and the url works but I think it has to be with Glide

Comment: I finally solved it. I was missing this line: .dontAnimate() in Glide script.

Comment: The animation had some kind of bug in the ImageViews. So I just removed it.